# How to implement Apache Camel Dynamic Router Pattern for flow chart based execution process

Tags: apache-camel, apache-camel-aws, apache-camel-mail

[image]How to implement Apache Camel Dynamic Router Pattern, for flow chart based execution process.
I have been through the links https://www.javainuse.com/camel/camel-dynamic-router-example, could not able to figure it out.

I want to create an API that processes all three steps.

1) First internally hits another API and get the response and transfer its response to the next stage i.e `Database`

2) The second step will perform the write operation to DB and route to different stage i.e`Response Handler`.

To conclude the above process, what I want to do is to create a different route for each stage and trigger or execute in a manner the process is defined.

Comment: Can you give more detail what you are trying to achieve? Better understanding your problem would help finding the right answer.

Comment: I'm still not sure what you're trying to achieve - is your routing dynamic? If so, what does it depend on? Your steps 1 and 2 seem straighforward, but I don't knwo what you mean by the final paragraph. Sorry!

Comment: Can you give a bit more information about what you're trying to achieve with this? What's the use case?

Comment: Could you add ypur code please? We can't debug ideas unfortunately.